# What optimal basis is when using revised simplex method

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Could anyone tell me what is an optimal basis(definition) when using revised simplex method to solve linear programming problem? I google it, but I cannot find the definition of optimal basis, except someone mentioned that if the reduced cost is less than zero, but the reduced cost is a vector, how could I say it is less than zero or not? Thank you very much!

Comment: I hope I get you right.  In the reversed simplex method, optimality always hold, so *everything* is optimal (but might not be feasible), and one tries to improve the feasibility.  In this sense, I would call "optimality" as "having all positive entries in the objective function row in the simplex tableau (in a dual simplex method)", so *my* definition of "optimal basis" is the collection of column vectors of the constraint matrix corresponding to the current basic variables in a dual simplex method.